# How to close a SSH connection that was opened to execute remote commands (-N option) in PHP?

Tags: php, ssh

in my PHP backend I need to open a SSH connection to communicate with a remote database. Therefore I do:

```
shell_exec("ssh -fNg -L 33066:127.0.0.1:33060 SSHUSER@SSHHOST stop 10");
```

The problem is that I need to use the `-N` option so that I can establish the database connection. **BUT** this `-N` prevents that the `stop 10` is working.

```
-N' Do not execute a remote command. This is useful for just forwarding ports (protocol version 2 only).
```

The question is now: how to quit the SSH connection after some seconds?

The function call is part of a REST backend and each request to the REST API opens a new SSH connection. Obviously I'm trying to prevent a "process overkill".

Please des anybody has an idea/solution for me?

Comment: You should go with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php, because you can close it anytime.

Comment: Your reason why you say you need "-N" doesn't make sense. What happens when you try it without the "-N" flag?

Comment: @Kenster the SSH tunnel isn't working without `-N`

Comment: @MarkusZeller I'll give this a try. Thx for the advice.

Comment: About the `-N flag`; How about to omit it and put an ampersand after the command to make it run in the background? Why do you close the tunnel everytime? Isn't it an option to keep it always alive?